# Flask not rendering template, probably an issue with file structure

Tags: python, templates, flask, render, file-structure

My structure for files is this.

```
-App
    -services
        - __init__.py
        - app_file.py
    -templates
        - hello.html
```

Inside app_file.py, I've got

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')
```

I know I have at least got a working "hello world" program, because this much worked

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'
```

However, when I attempt the templated html, I get this error.

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
```

As I said, I'm almost positive it is something with my file structure, so I posted only what I feel is necesary to determine if I am right or not, but will post more upon request. Help please?

Comment: what is the value of your `template_path` parameter to `Flask`?

Comment: haven't done it yet, see my comment addressed to Martijin Peters

Answer (score 3):

`templates` should be a subfolder of where the `services` package, or you need to set a custom [`template_folder` argument](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#application-object) when creating the `Flask()` app object:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')
```

Comment: do you know what the difference between "from flask import Module" vs "from flask import Flask" is? I am using the "Module" import which looks to be about the same, but it isn't working as expected " got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_folder'"

Comment: A `Module` is the predecessor of [Blueprints](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/blueprints/); these have been deprecated since Flask 0.7 and under the hood they are now just Blueprints with a hardcoded `template_folder` argument. Use a Blueprint instead.

Comment: See the [upgrading to 0.7 documentation](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrading/#blueprint-support) as well.

Comment: Saying cannot import name Blueprint.. is an install necesary, or some other form of upgrade?

Comment: If you have a setup with Flask 0.6 or older installed, you cannot use Blueprints. You'd either have to upgrade your setup, or stick to Modules. If you choose to stick with the older Flask version, you'll *have* to move the `templates` directory as that version of Flask doesn't support setting a different directory.